# PHP/Apache/Sendmail Received: (from apache@localhost)

Tags: php, apache, sendmail

I am trying to send mail using **PHP mail function and sendmail** on RHEL. There is a line in the header, Received: (from apache@localhost), which is causing some recipients to drop the message. I need to get this portion of the header replaced with a proper user/domain: (lets say user@example.com). I have been fighting with this for a while, I am just not sure what to do. Discussions are just all over the place on the web. **The scripts do specify the sender.**

Here is an example of the SMTP header:

```
Received: from <omitted> (<omitted> [127.0.0.1])
    by <omitted> (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id rADEwvp4003653
    for <omitted>; Wed, 13 Nov 2013 09:58:57 -0500
Received: (from apache@localhost)
    by <omitted> (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id rADEwvEj003650;
    Wed, 13 Nov 2013 09:58:57 -0500
Date: Wed, 13 Nov 2013 09:58:57 -0500
Message-Id: <omitted>
To: <omitted>
Subject: <omitted>
From: user@example.com
Reply-To: user@example.com
```

Comment: you are using POSTFIX ?

Comment: Would the following make a difference? `Received: from YOUR_CHOICE (apache@localhost) ...`

Comment: @Satya Based on info (version numbers) in `Received:` headers it is sendmail.

Answer (score 1):

if you use standard `mail()` function there is a hidden parameter , try to pass "-fuser@domain" as fifth parameter 
[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3374)

Comment: Maybe you can try other php mailers : PHPMailer,or Swift Mailer or just send via smtp (for ex:google), and the last that I can think of is forcing the sender email statically in your sendmail config.

Answer (score 0):

Pass somethings like this as fourth parameter. It should be enough to change From field, *but will not protect your mails from SPAM folder* because it requires more complcated stuff like SPF records and DKIM keys.

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Oops. I didn't noticed that there is already "From" fields. My bad.